# Can someone help to find this slider?

Tags: javascript, slider

In my order, my employer ask me to use this slider -
http://www.prestonbailey.com/
I haven't seen something like that before. Maybe someone knows what is it or can help to find it. I will be very grateful for that. Thanks!

Comment: Open Developer Tools and see what code it's using.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some libraries that can help you achieve this:

- [TwentyTwenty](http://zurb.com/playground/twentytwenty)
- [JuxtaposeJS](https://github.com/NUKnightLab/juxtapose)

Here's [a way to do it without a library](http://thenewcode.com/819/A-Before-And-After-Image-Comparison-Slide-Control-in-HTML5).